# Execute javascript again with load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reload

I want to create a "next" button which display different profiles. For that, I want to reload the div. I have successfull create the function, but when It's reload 1 time, javascript is not load after, so my button click function doesn't work.
My code :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="my" id="profile_rd">
            <div class="ibox-content text-center" id="ok">
                <h1>Profile example</h1>
                  <a class="btn btn-xs btn-prim-red" id="please_next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> Next</a> <!-- Here, we can click and execute the function one time , after, click doesn't work -->

            </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $('#please_next').click(function(){
                $('#profile_rd').load(document.URL + ' #ok');
                return false;
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Its not clicking second time because when you click first time on please_next button DOM content loaded with new data and second time DOM does not find 'please_next', So use 'on' or 'delegate' event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
$('#please_next').click(function(){
    $('#profile_rd').load(document.URL + ' #ok');
    return false;
});
```

to

```
$(document).on( 'click', '#please_next', function(){
    $('#profile_rd').load(document.URL + ' #ok');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reloading the document so after the first click on the button, the DOM can't find the element that you're trying to attach the event to. You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).